# Call object method for a list of objects in C++

Tags: c++, function, object

How can I devise a way to call an object method for each object provided to a function?

I.e.,

```
ResetAll(obj1, obj2, obj3, ...)
```

will call `obj1.Reset()`, `obj2.Reset()`, etc...

The objects are not in a List or any other STL container.

Comment: I assume this function takes a variable amount of arguments? (Variadic function)

Comment: I do not see a problem with either putting the objects into a container via pointer or else calling the function once for each object. Why do these methods not work for you?

Comment: I can't use any C++11 features unfortunately.

Comment: An `std::vector` is not C++11.

Comment: @birryree nor STL containers.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps a variadic template:

```
template <typename ...Objs> struct Resetter;

template <typename Obj, typename ...Rest> struct Resetter<Obj, Rest>
{
  static inline void reset(Obj && obj, Rest &&... rest)
  {
    std::forward<Obj>(obj).Reset();
    Resetter<Rest...>::reset(std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
  }
};

template <> struct Resetter<> { static inline void reset() { }; };

// Type-deducing helper
template <typename ...Objs> inline void ResetAll(Objs &&... objs)
{
  Resetter<Objs...>::Reset(std::forward<Objs>(objs)...);
}
```

Usage:

```
ResetAll(ob1, obj2, some_obj, another_obj);
```

Comment: It should be noted that this will only work with pretty recent versions of compilers, as it's part of the brand new C++11 standard.

Comment: Hi @KerrekSB Unfortunately I won't be able to use any C++11 specific features.  Can you think of any other way?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: True, though if you like you can use the Microsoft Trick to simulate variadic templates on old compilers (up to a certain, fixed number of parameters).

Comment: @chriskirk: Well, see my comment to Joachim. Acutally I was thinking variadic macros at first, but I got stuck. Let me rethink that, maybe that's possible after all.

Comment: @chriskirk: Are you saying you *have* GCC 4.6.1? Just add `-std=c++0x` to the command then! Anyway, I don't think you can do this with the preprocessor alone, because you can't call macros recursively and there's no parameter pack expansion for macros. I'd go with this C++ solution if at all possible.

Comment: @chriskirk, gcc 4.6.1 implements variadic templates, but if you can't use c++11 or containers, one of the  alternatives is to pass an array of pointers to your objects along with the size of the array, like you'd do in C.

Answer (score 2):

Proof of concept, because writing dubious C++ code is fun:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define Invoke(A, T,M,...)\
    do{\
        struct _{ \
            _& operator,(T* value){ \
                value->M A ; \
                return *this; \
            } \
        } _; _, __VA_ARGS__; \
    }while(0)

#define m_a_all(...) Invoke( (), Obj,m_a,__VA_ARGS__)
#define m_b_all(...) Invoke( (), Obj,m_b,__VA_ARGS__)
#define m_c_all(A, ...) Invoke(A, Obj,m_c,__VA_ARGS__)

class Obj{
public:
    virtual void m_a(){
        cout << "Obj::m_a " << this << endl;
    }
    virtual void m_b(){
        cout << "Obj::m_b " << this << endl;
    }
    virtual void m_c(int a, double b){
        cout << "Obj::m_c(" << a <<"," << b<< ") " << this << endl;
    }
};
class Derived : public Obj{
public:
    virtual void m_a(){
        cout << "Derived::m_a " << this << endl;
    }
    virtual void m_b(){
        cout << "Derived::m_b " << this << endl;
    }
    virtual void m_c(int a, double b){
        cout << "Derived::m_c(" << a <<"," << b<< ") " << this << endl;
    }
};

int main(){

    Obj *o1 = new Obj(), *o2 = new Obj(), *o3 = new Derived();

    m_a_all(o1, o2, o3);
    cout<<endl;
    m_a_all(o1);
    cout<<endl;
    m_b_all(o1, o2, o3);
    cout<<endl;
    m_c_all( (3,42.0), o1, o2, o3);

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
Obj::m_a 0x9e0a008
Obj::m_a 0x9e0a018
Derived::m_a 0x9e0a028

Obj::m_a 0x9e0a008

Obj::m_b 0x9e0a008
Obj::m_b 0x9e0a018
Derived::m_b 0x9e0a028

Obj::m_c(3,42) 0x9e0a008
Obj::m_c(3,42) 0x9e0a018
Derived::m_c(3,42) 0x9e0a028
```

The chained `operator,` overload allows `__VA_ARGS__` to be used.
One limitation is that it can only be used if all arguments share a base type, for which the method to be called is defined.

This should have minimal overhead and doesn't depend on any libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If you could accept some heavy preprocessor abuse with [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html):

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define CALL_RESET(z, n, data) BOOST_PP_CAT(p, n).Reset();

#define GENERATE_VARIADIC_FUNCTION(z, n, data) \
    template <BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS_Z(z, BOOST_PP_INC(n), typename T)> \
    void ResetAll(BOOST_PP_ENUM_BINARY_PARAMS_Z(z, BOOST_PP_INC(n), T, & p)) \
    { \
        BOOST_PP_CAT(BOOST_PP_REPEAT_, z)(BOOST_PP_INC(n), CALL_RESET, ) \
    }

/* ^ this generates the function

   template <typename T0, typename T1, typename T2, ...>
   void ResetAll(T0& p0, T1& p1, T2& p2, ...)
   {
      p0.Reset(); p1.Reset(); p2.Reset(); ...
   }

*/

BOOST_PP_REPEAT(BOOST_PP_LIMIT_REPEAT, GENERATE_VARIADIC_FUNCTION, )
// ^ and this creates all of the above up to 256.
```

For example,

```
#include <cstdio>

struct Obj1 { void Reset() { printf("1\n"); } };
struct Obj2 { void Reset() { printf("2\n"); } };
struct Obj3 { void Reset() { printf("3\n"); } };

int main()
{
    Obj1 o1;
    Obj2 o2;
    Obj3 o3;
    ResetAll(o1, o2, o3, o2, o1, o3);
    return 0;
}
```

will print '1 2 3 2 1 3' on screen (proof: http://ideone.com/FRNvJ).

(BTW, this will generate an insurmountable wall of error messages if one of the input is an rvalue.)